# Do all Linux flavors use /etc/ld.so.preload?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I'm reading a set of instructions for a Linux shared library, jemalloc, which is to be preloaded at runtime because it overloads functions like malloc.  One way to cause the library to be preloaded (i.e. loaded at program startup before any other shared libraries that might have functions of the same names) is to make an entry in the system variable `LD_PRELOAD`; another way is to make an entry in the file `/etc/ld.so.preload` .  The latter method would make it the default for all users, not just a single instance.  But the author of the instructions for the latter said it was only known to work on Debian Linux.  I've been searching for documentation that would clearly answer:  Is `/etc/ld.so.preload` used in all Linux flavors; all Unix flavors; or just certain ones?

Answer (score 2):

The `/etc/ld.so.preload` is a feature of GLIBC.

> all Linux flavors

Most, but *not all*, Linux distributions do use GLIBC, and it will work on them.

> all Unix flavors

Most non-Linux UNIX flavors *do not* use GLIBC, and so it will not work on them.